# flash remoting CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am trying to add the remoting scripts  in flash CS5
However, the actionscript is fine, the problem is i cant find the flash remoting component in any of the components panels.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Flash Remoting component for AS3. See this http://curiousmindsmedia.wordpress.com/2008/01/29/flash-remoting-as2-vs-as3/

Comment: Excellent! Just what i was looking for.